# How to find the string that contains substring of another string as a substring in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

```
$a = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.";
$b = array("The lazy dog sleeps under the tree.", "...", ...);
```

How can I find `$b[0]` that contains "lazy dog" in string `$a?` The problem is, I don't know beforehand that the searched substring is "lazy dog", something like array_intersect for arrays.

Comment: It's a difficult problem, and regex are very limited to do that (even if you build the pattern to solve the problem, when the amount of text will grow, the complexity will increase very fast). So regex is not the solution to do that. You need to split your strings by words and store positions in the string for each words, then use `array_intersect` to reduce the arrays size.

Comment: Many permutations there.

Comment: Investigate how `Beyond Compare` does it. And for sure its not done with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisbloom7/1021218#file-longest_common_substring_example-php) from github might need a little tweaking, but should get you what you want:

```
function longest_common_substring($words) {
    $words = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', $words));
    $sort_by_strlen = create_function('$a, $b', 'if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { return strcmp($a, $b); } return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;');
    usort($words, $sort_by_strlen);
    $longest_common_substring = array();
    $shortest_string = str_split(array_shift($words));
    while (sizeof($shortest_string)) {
        array_unshift($longest_common_substring, '');
        foreach ($shortest_string as $ci => $char) {
            foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
                if (!strstr($word, $longest_common_substring[0] . $char)) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
            $longest_common_substring[0] .= $char;
        }
        array_shift($shortest_string);
    }

    usort($longest_common_substring, $sort_by_strlen);
    return trim(array_pop($longest_common_substring));
}

// usage:
echo longest_common_substring(array('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog', 'I jumped over the lazy bear'));
```

Comment: This clearly solves my problem. Thank you very much.